# Failed to read integer using fscanf in c

Tags: c, scanf

```
FILE *fin = fopen("figura.in", "r");
if(fscanf(fin, "%d %d %d %d", &int[0], &int[1], &int[2], &int[3]) == 1)     {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", int[0], int[1], int[2], int[3]);
    } else {
        printf("failed to read integer.\n");
    }
```

I get failed to read integer. The file is okay, it consists 4 integers. What is wrong?

Comment: Please don't use `int` for a dummy variable name: it is a **keyword**. I suggest `dummy_int` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be checking to see if `fscanf` returns 4, the number of inputs in your format string:

```
if(fscanf(fin, "%d %d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3]) == 4)
```

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

Comment: are you sure its &int[0], &int[1].. aren't they "keywords"?